# Big data migration from Oracle to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, bigdata, database-migration

I received over 100GB of data with 67million records from one of the retailers.  My objective is to do some market-basket analysis and CLV. This data is a direct sql dump from one of the tables with 70 columns.  I'm trying to find a way to extract information from this data as managing itself in a small laptop/desktop setup is becoming time consuming.   I considered the following options

- Parse the data and convert the same to CSV format. File size might come down to around 35-40GB as more than half of the information in each records is column names.  However, I may still have to use a db as I cant use R or Excel with 66 million records.
- Migrate the data to mysql db.  Unfortunately I don't have the schema for the table and I'm trying to recreate the schema looking at the data.  I may have to replace `to_date()` in the data dump to `str_to_date()` to match with MySQL format.

Are there any better way to handle this?  All that I need to do is extract the data from the sql dump by running some queries. Hadoop etc. are options, but I dont have the infrastructure to setup a cluster. I'm considering mysql as I have storage space and some memory to spare.

Suppose I go in the MySQL path, how would I import the data?  I'm considering one of the following

- Use `sed` and replace `to_date()` with appropriate `str_to_date()` inline. Note that, I need to do this for a 100GB file.  Then import the data using `mysql` CLI.
- Write python/perl script that will read the file, convert the data and write to mysql directly.

What would be faster?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion writing a script will be faster, because you are going to skip the SED part.

I think that you need to setup a server on a separate PC, and run the script from your laptop.

Also use tail to faster get a part from the bottom of this large file, in order to test your script on that part before you run it on this 100GB file.

Comment: Found that `gshuf` or  `shuf` is more effective to get a random sample from the file.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with the MySQL path.  I created the schema looking at the data (had to increase a few of the column size as there were unexpected variations in the data) and wrote a python script using [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/) module.  Import completed in 4hr 40mins on my 2011 MacBook Pro with 8154 failures out of 67 million records.  Those failures were mostly data issues. Both client and server are running on my MBP.

@kpopovbg, yes, writing script was faster.  Thank you.